# JS & HTML - how can i embed a random video in a <section>?

Tags: javascript, html

**I want to play a random video on my website.** But I don't know how I can make that, because I'm a noob with HTML & JSS. I searched for a simple way to do that, but I can't find a solution.

Thats my code on the Website, where the different videos should come. Sadly, this doesn't work. He tries to find a file named "video/trailer1.mp4, video/trailer2.mp4"

```
<section data-video-path="video/trailer1.mp4, video/trailer2.mp4"></section>
```

Is it possible to add a filename to "trailer1" with a comma or something? Is there an easy way to add a video and it get picked randomly which one is played?

I found a function, that maybe helps to implement random videos. Can i maybe implement the random video thing with the { and } ?

```
data-plugin-options="{'posterType': 'jpg', 'position': '50% 50%'}"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511665/load-and-shuffle-videos-each-time-you-enter-site

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871537/how-to-randomize-video-on-click-and-on-page-load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `<video>` element to play video in the HTML

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)

```html
<video class="my-video" controls muted loop autoplay></video>
```

If you want to change the video source to be a random one then in JavaScrpit:

```js
const possibleVideos = ["video/trailer1.mp4", "video/trailer2.mp4"];
const randomVideo = possibleVideos[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleVideos.length)];

document.querySelector('video.my-video').src = randomVideo;
```

ref: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a video from YouTube
It Is The Simple Way

```html
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting but OP wanted a random video in the `src`

Comment: You Can Change It

Comment: Yes you can but you are just posting some HTML code and not necessarily how to pull the random files.